# Techniques for turning recursive functions into iterators in Rust?

Tags: recursion, rust, iterator

I'm struggling to turn a simple recursive function into a simple iterator. The problem is that the recursive function maintains state in its local variables and call stack -- and to turn this into a rust iterator means basically externalizing all the function state into mutable properties on some custom iterator struct. It's quite a messy endeavor.

In a language like javascript or python, `yield` comes to the rescue. Are there any techniques in Rust to help manage this complexity?

Simple example using `yield` (pseudocode):

```
function one_level(state, depth, max_depth) {
  if depth == max_depth {
    return
  }
  for s in next_states_from(state) {
    yield state_to_value(s);
    yield one_level(s, depth+1, max_depth);
  }
}
```

To make something similar work in Rust, I'm basically creating a `Vec<Vec<State>>` on my iterator struct, to reflect the data returned by `next_states_from` at each level of the call stack. Then for each `next()` invocation, carefully popping pieces off of this to restore state. I feel like I may be missing something.

Comment: Perhaps https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/generators.html

Comment: I'd look into redesigning your recursive function into something that could be applied to [this pattern](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00a850a5142a3f1fea840fa5a898693e). Additionally, it sounds like you're traversing a tree, which is plausible to implement using this pattern with a `Vec` temporary which stores previous unvisited nodes and which iare left to visit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are performing a (depth-limited) [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on your state graph. You can do it iteratively by using a single stack of unprocessed subtrees(depending on your state graph structure).

```
struct Iter {
    stack: Vec<(State, u32)>,
    max_depth: u32,
}

impl Iter {
    fn new(root: State, max_depth: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            stack: vec![(root, 0)],
            max_depth
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Iter {
    type Item = u32; // return type of state_to_value
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let (state, depth) = self.stack.pop()?;
        if depth < self.max_depth {
            for s in next_states_from(state) {
                self.stack.push((s, depth+1));
            }
        }
        return Some(state_to_value(state));
    }
}
```

There are some slight differences to your code:

- The iterator yields the value of the root element, while your version does not. This can be easily fixed using `.skip(1)`
- Children are processed in right-to-left order (reversed from the result of `next_states_from`). Otherwise, you will need to reverse the order of pushing the next states (depending on the result type of `next_states_from` you can just use `.rev()`, otherwise you will need a temporary)

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful! (My specific situation is somewhat more complex because I need to be able to detect when I am popping up a level in my DFS to manage some related state -- but I could track this by using a `last_processed_depth` variable on my iterator struct, or some such.)