# More techniques for recursive patterns in iteration

Tags: recursion, rust, iterator, iteration, state

Building on [Techniques for turning recursive functions into iterators in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827188/techniques-for-turning-recursive-functions-into-iterators-in-rust), I'd like to explore the challenges of iterators.

Let's think about a recursive yield-based function with slightly more complex control flow:

```
function one_level(state, depth, max_depth) {
  if depth == max_depth {
    return
  }
  if external_condition(state) {                 // location-1
     for s in next_states_from(state) {          // loop-1
       yield state_to_value(s);
       yield one_level(s, depth+1, max_depth); 
     }
  } else {
     for s in other_next_state_from(state) {     // loop-2
       yield one_level(s, depth+1, max_depth)    // location-2
     }
  }
}
```

Here things get interesting because there are:

- conditional branches
- multiple recursion points

Managing all of this in a Rust iterator, I find myself basically decorating my state object with properties like `location_1_reached:bool` so that I can set these in my `next()` function before returning. Then I need to litter my code with checks to see how far we got on the previous time through this stack frame's state. Again, I'm struggling to handle this in a clean fashion.

I'd be most interested in suggestions. As a hint of the pain I'm in, here's the kind of structs I've been defining to make this work today:

```rust
struct MyIteratorStackFrame<'a> {
    arg_1: usize,
    arg_2: Point,
    loop_1_values: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a State> + 'a>,
    loop_2_values: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a State> + 'a>,
    location_1_reached: bool,
    location_2_reached: bool
}

struct MyIterator<'a> {
    max_depth: usize,
    stack: Vec<MyIteratorStackFrame<'a>>,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are talking about is a 'state machine', and it is best represented in Rust using an enum:

```
enum Frame {
    NextStates(NextStatesIterator, State),
    OtherStates(OtherStatesIterator)
}
struct Iterator {
    stack: Vec<Frame>, 
}
```

Comment: I guess what I'm struggling with is how to write idiomatic procedural code for the iterator in this case; how do you succinctly and clearly represent program flow? With multiple return points, managing the details quickly becomes very challenging.